# Using Jade in Meteorjs

Tags: meteor, pug, spacebars

Im studying the book Meteor in action, in the book authors use html/js, but i prefer jade/coffee. I've met some troubles with this piece of code:

```
<template name="templateElseBlock">
  <h3>templateElseBlock template</h3>
  {{#isFemale gender}} Mrs. {{else}} Mr. {{/isFemale}}
</template>

<template name="isFemale">
  {{#if eq this 'w'}}
    {{> Template.contentBlock}}
  {{else}}
    {{> Template.elseBlock}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

I tried something like this and got only errors

```
 While building the application:
   client/main.jade: Jade syntax error: unexpected token "indent"
   <runJavaScript-57>:73:14: Cannot read property 'head' of undefined
   (compiling client/main.jade) (at fileModeHandler)


template(name='templateElseBlock')
  isFemale gender
    | Mrs.
  else
    | Mr.

template(name="isFemale")
  if eq #{this} 'w'
    +Template.contentBlock
  else
    +Template.elseBlock
```

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: please, specify which errors do you have

Comment: I wrote above the whole error i got

Answer (score 0):

After several google pages, I got that code needs only one symbol +isFemale.

The answer:

```
template(name='elseBlock')
  +isFemale gender
    | Mrs.
  else
    | Mr.


  template(name="isFemale")
    if eq this 'w'
     +Template.contentBlock
    else
     +Template.elseBlock
```